# USB To 3.5mm Jack mircophone

Tags: microphone

I want to record live music directly from my sound board on my Samsung Galaxy. I assume this would be done by connecting the 3.5mm microphone jack on my sound board to the Galaxy's USB port.  There are plenty of products that work on Windows, but what about Android?

Comment: Could you please clarify? Am I right that you want to connect your Phone's USB port with the USB connector of a USB-2-Audio adapter and then connect this 3.5mm port to your soundboard?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. If there is another way then I'd like to know, please.

Comment: That a equivalent of looking for a USB-OTG mechanism which may or may not be supported by the kernel?

Answer (score 1):

I assume the USB connection isn't the main point? You could look into a TRRS splitter to fit your 3,5mm plug into the headset jack on your phone. [Here's](http://eu.startech.com/Cables/Audio-Video/Audio-Cables/35mm-4-Position-to-2x-3-Position-35mm-Headset-Splitter-Adapter-Male-to-Female~MUYHSMFF) one example, just to give you an idea of what I mean.

This way you can use a normal recording app to capture analog audio from your soundboard. Just be careful to check the levels since the jack isn't a line in jack, but a mic in jack.

Comment: You are correct that the USB connection is not the main point.  That seems like the way to go.  Thanks for answering.